# Equal padding between 4 divs without padding first and last div

Tags: css, media-queries

Im trying to pad 4 divs apart, **I would like the first and last div edges to be at the edge of the page**, and an equal space between each middle divs. I cant seem to be able to remove the padding from the last div without the div becoming slightly larger than the others.

I also need to divs to change size if the user is viewing on a small screen like a tablet or mobile. Meaning on a mobile, all divs will be at the edge of the screen and padding just between div1 - div2 and div3 - div4

The only way ive managed to achieve almost my goal was to pad each div 5px left and right, but then the first and last divs are not on the page edge.

Heres is a fiddle with my code, resize the screen for it to change size.

https://jsfiddle.net/cmjuc4e8/

Any help would be apprciated!!

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<body>

<div class="home-category-box">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
<div style="padding:10px; font-size:16px; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color: #C50132;"><b>TITLE 1</b><br>####</div>
</div>

<div class="home-category-box">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
<div style="padding:10px; font-size:16px; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color: #C50132;"><b>TITLE 2</b><br>####</div>

</div>

<div class="home-category-box">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
<div style="padding:10px; font-size:16px; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color: #C50132;"><b>TITLE 3</b><br>####</div>
</div>

<div class="home-category-box">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
<div style="padding:10px; font-size:16px; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color: #C50132;"><b>TITLE 4</b><br>####</div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
.home-category-box {
width: 25%;
display: block;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding-right:15px;
margin-bottom:15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:760px){

.home-category-box {
width: 50%;
display: block;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

}
```

Comment: Is flex-box an option?

Comment: Im not familiar with that :( I dont know what that does.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a new project I recommend that you use [flexbox](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties). Much easier than floats once you get the hang of it.

Place a row in a containing element and add a negative left and right margin equal to that of the padding on the left and right sides. The negative margin will pull the inner elements outside of the parent element. This is the same approach that frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) use.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -5px;
}

.home-category-box {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box-meta {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C50132;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media ( min-width: 760px ) {
  .home-category-box {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box-row">

  <div class="home-category-box">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
    <div class="box-meta">
      <div class="box-title">TITLE 1</div>
      <div class="box-other">####</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="home-category-box">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
    <div class="box-meta">
      <div class="box-title">TITLE 2</div>
      <div class="box-other">####</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="home-category-box">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
    <div class="box-meta">
      <div class="box-title">TITLE 3</div>
      <div class="box-other">####</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="home-category-box">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
    <div class="box-meta">
      <div class="box-title">TITLE 4</div>
      <div class="box-other">####</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I really like this idea but there must be something wrong with my implementation.  The -5px left/right margins are only pulling on the left side so the left side is flush with the page but the right side has a 10px space (5px padding & -5px margin from the left pull)

Comment: Resolved the issue- I had `width: 100%;` on what would be the equivalent of the `.box-row` element here.  Overrode that with `width: unset` and I'm good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're targeting relatively modern browsers you have the option of using either CSS flexbox:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {

  /* sets defaults for all elements and the ::before and
     ::after pseudo-elements: */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {

  /* causes the <body> to use the flex layout: */
  display: flex;

  /* allows content to wrap to a new row: */
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  /* causes the direction of content flow
     to run along 'rows' (as opposed to
     columns) in the DOM order (rather than
     row-reverse which would reverse the flow): */
  flex-direction: row;

  /* places the first and last element at the edges
     of the parent element, with space between sibling
     elements: */
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: auto;

  /* aligns the contents with equal space around (above
     and below) in the cross-axis of the content-flow: */
  align-content: space-around;

  /* setting the width to the width of the viewport: */
  width: 100vw;
}

.home-category-box {

  /* prevents the elements from growing/shrinking as the
     parent element, or viewport, resizes in respects
     to siblings: */
  flex: 0 0 auto;

  /* to force an obvious space between elements; adjust to
     taste: */
  width: 20%;
}

.home-category-box>img+div {

  /* all CSS here is from the in-line style attribute
     that made the HTML look messy; adjust to taste: */
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C50132;
}


/* for 'small' screens: */
@media screen and (max-width:760px) {

  /* changes the width of the matching elements,
     to force only two items per line: */
  .home-category-box {
    width: 45%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="home-category-box">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
  <div><b>TITLE 1</b>
    <br>####</div>
</div>

<div class="home-category-box">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
  <div><b>TITLE 2</b>
    <br>####</div>

</div>

<div class="home-category-box">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
  <div><b>TITLE 3</b>
    <br>####</div>
</div>

<div class="home-category-box">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
  <div><b>TITLE 4</b>
    <br>####</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cmjuc4e8/1/).

Or CSS grid:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {

  /* causes the <body> to use CSS grid layout,
     and causes its children to be laid out as
     grid-items: */
  display: grid;

  /* defines four columns, each of which is
     one fractional unit: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);

  /* gutter between columns: */
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;

  /* gutter between rows: */
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
  width: 100vw;
}

.home-category-box>img+div {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C50132;
}

@media screen and (max-width:760px) {
  body {

    /* on 'small' screens we define a two-column
       layout; and rely on the grid-layout to
       place elements beyond the second on
       implicit rows: */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="home-category-box">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
  <div><b>TITLE 1</b>
    <br>####</div>
</div>

<div class="home-category-box">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
  <div><b>TITLE 2</b>
    <br>####</div>

</div>

<div class="home-category-box">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
  <div><b>TITLE 3</b>
    <br>####</div>
</div>

<div class="home-category-box">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="100%">
  <div><b>TITLE 4</b>
    <br>####</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cmjuc4e8/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following, applying padding the left and right sides of only the inner divs.

```
.home-cateogry-box {
display: block;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-bottom: 15px;

.home-category-box:not(:first-child),
.home-category-box:not(:last-child) {
padding: 0 15px;
}
```